# CSS - Keep paragraph aspect ratio and fit content

Tags: html, css

Is there any pure CSS workaround to format a paragraph which:

- Width and height fit to content
- Maintains a specific aspect ratio as it shrinks or grows

I have searched around but only found solutions which do not fit to content. Thanks.

*Edit: Adding code I am working with. I'm trying to make the paragraph to have aspect ratio 1:1 in which its size will fit the text content inside (no extra spaces). The text content is dynamic.*

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at ante vitae velit tempus molestie eu ut dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.container {
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  background: red;
}

p {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pynnl/pen/MGWNMK)

***Edit 2:*** This is what I'm trying to achieve, but without javascript

```js
const ratio = 16 / 9 // width/height aspect ratio

let p = $('p')
let lh = parseFloat(p.css('line-height'))

p.on('input', () => {
  let divW = $('div').width()
  p.width(`${(Math.sqrt(ratio*divW*lh)+lh)/divW*100}%`)
})

p.trigger('input')
```

```css
div {
  width: max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  visibility: hidden;
}

p {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background: lightblue;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at ante vitae velit tempus molestie eu ut dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add the code you are working with? Thanks

Comment: @sol Code added, thank you

Comment: Is the content dynamic?

Comment: @sol Yes it is dynamic

Comment: Do you want the height and width to be same?

Comment: @SyamPillai Yes, I want it to be 1:1 or a specific ratio